# Julia Issues with getline()

Tags: julia

To fetch value at the execution stage I have used below getline() function but when it comes to fetching only one value it is being stored in array format which restricts me to use this value in future calculations. However, it works fine for multiple input values.

```
  getline(q=STDIN)= map(parse, split(readline(q)))
    q =getline(STDIN)
```

When i input value **8** it stores as **[8]** like an array format. Can someone help me to store the value as Int64 format? 
Note: I'm writing Julia code in a .jl file and using it in REPL by include(file.jl) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is so that one know that q is always going to be an array no matter whether you give 1 or >1 arguments. See here for a fuller explanation as to why: [1-element Array to scalar in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079428/1-element-array-to-scalar-in-julia/39079708#39079708).

For now you can just use the bottom line here if you want.

```
q = [8]
# If q is length one then q is the first element of q
(length(q) == 1) && (q = q[1])
```

To be extra sure you could even:

```
(length(q) == 1) && (q = Int64(q[1]))
```

or

```
@assert typeof(q) == Int64
```

**Edited to reflect comments:** 
This is so that `split()` has the simplest possible behaviour i.e. it always returns an array. When you split a string, you don't know in advance how many fields you will get so the simplest thing to do is return an array of N values for N fields, no matter what N is.

If a different type was returned then calling e.g. `length(split(s))` to count the number of fields may return an unexpected result (like the length of the value/string itself). Thanks for the explanation @ Jeff Bezanson

Comment: It's not really related to type stability; it's just that `split` always returns an array. When you split a string, you don't know in advance how many fields you will get. The simplest behavior is to return an array of N values for N fields, no matter what N is. Returning a different type when N==1 would be more confusing for everybody; e.g. code like `length(split(s))` to count the number of fields would be broken.